# What would it be like to participate in a (coronavirus) challenge trial, in the US?

Tags: covid-19, exercise, research, clinical-study, united-states

I am strongly considering volunteering for any COVID human challenge trial that becomes available near me (midwestern United States). I am willing to undergo long-term isolation. However, I am not willing to significantly disrupt my work life. That means I want free time with my computer, significant private time, and the opportunity to be physically active.

Can anyone give me an educated guess about whether, as a participant in such a trial, I would have access to things like free time, space to exercise, and a personal computer? I presume that the answer is "the range of situations is extremely wide, and the answer depends on a bunch of factors." However, I would appreciate any suggestive information. I would also appreciate advice in how best to phrase these questions to get good answers from prospective trial administrators.

Thanks!

Comment: I've added the US tag based on another q of yours. Clinical trials can differ in some ways between countries. Which live challnge trial are you thinking of? As far as I know all Covid-19 vaccine trials in the US for now exclude such live challenges... (Instead they do year-long monitoring.)

Comment: Even assuming the US gov't changes its mind about this, the chance of live-challenge trial "available near you" are nearly zero, unless you live in Bethesda, MD, or thereabout. They probably won't risk causing an outbreak somewhere where there are no special facilities.

Comment: @Fizz Influenza challenge trials have been conducted at several other facilities as well. Given the extent of community spread of the virus I would expect a similar level of containment to influenza. But yes, one would likely need to be near one of those facilities to participate.

Comment: @BryanKrause: yes but the CFR from influenza is lower. The fact that no live challenge trials have been announced for Covid-19 probably factors that in. I vaguely recall that some influenza live challenges were done at one of the US army labs, but with few participants.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I see there's a review paper on those; https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fcimb.2019.00107/full According to that the only US study in the last 20 years or so was https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4342672/ at NIH.

Comment: @Fizz I'm guessing the relative novelty of the vaccine targets is a bigger stumbling block for now; they are in a much more developmental stage than influenza vaccines/treatments, and it's still too early to narrow down to a particular candidate that would be appropriate for a challenge trial.

Comment: Also see https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/influenza-human-challenge-study-begins-nih-sponsored-clinical-trial-units - an ongoing influenza trial at: "University of Maryland School of Medicine, Baltimore; Saint Louis University, St. Louis, MO; Duke University, Durham, NC; and Cincinnati (OH) Children’s Hospital"

Comment: @BryanKrause: Actually they mention some subsequent ones (the hiatus was 2005-2015) there were a few more after that e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4959521/ or https://bmcinfectdis.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12879-018-3220-8 but those were also at NIH. I think the one you found might be first done elsewhere in the US since 2005.

Comment: @Fizz https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31978354?dopt=Abstract seems to be another done in the US recently, at a private lab.

Comment: +1 for your courage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to talk to the staff who are recruiting patients; I'm not aware of any such trials that have started anywhere yet. I would expect you would have access to most of those things depending on what your definitions are of private time and physical activity.

As far as asking questions, just be direct and define your terms. "Can I bring my computer and have internet access" might not be specific enough if your question is really "Can I work an uninterrupted full-time schedule from 8 am to 5 pm using my computer?" - the answer to that is likely no, but you might get an idea of what interruptions you can expect, how often, etc, and also how flexible those interruptions can be.

An example facility that is capable of appropriate isolation and has been used in influenza challenge trials is at NIH; their tour video at the page linked below might be a good place to start for some of your questions.

https://www.niaid.nih.gov/news-events/scsu-video-tour

I think the whole video is probably useful to someone considering participating in a trial, but I'd note that around 12 minutes they are touring a patient room and shortly after there is some discussion of what the patients participating in clinical trials there can bring in, which includes bringing in computers for entertainment and work.

Again, I wouldn't use this video as a guarantee of anything for a specific trial you might be involved in, so ask your specific questions to those trial staff.

If you do participate, you of course may develop symptoms that interfere with all the things you mentioned.